# OR statement for foursquare API query search term

Tags: api, foursquare

Is there some way to use an "OR" statement for the "query" parameter in the "explore" endpoint https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore ?
For example, if I want to explore "wifi" OR "wi-fi" venues in a single API request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

foursquare's query field only supports keywords -- it doesn't include support for operators like "OR."